# How to create graphs similar to git branches using React?

Tags: reactjs, graph, gitgraph.js

I want to add graphs in React similar to the below attached image. Is there any package available of achieving so? Or is it possible to make it using the Graph data structure?

[image]

Comment: Software recommendation questions are **off-topic** on Stack Overflow for the reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic). Can you please [edit] to remove that request?

Answer (score 0):

You can look out for [@gitgraph/react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@gitgraph/react) package, which provides a plenty of customization to visualize a graph.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).